# dynamically change binding in textboxes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have four text-boxes arranged column wise with each column having two textbox.

```
| Textbox 1 |             | Textbox 2 |
| Textbox 3 |             | Textbox 4 |
```

And Textbox 1 and 3 will have some value. What I am trying to achieve is if I first click Textbox 1 and then Textbox 2, then the Tb 2 should bind to Tb1. Next If i click Tb3 and then tb 2 then the binding of tb2 should be changed to that of tb3.

Does angular provide any way to achieve this? Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: While you have given an example of how you expect your bindings to take place, its too specific - can you generalize it - that is, what is the logic of determining the binding of any textbox?

Comment: who determines what binds with what is upto the user. What I am trying to achieve is, if the user wants to bind to tb1 and tb4, all he has to do is first click on tb1 and then on tb4. Next if he wants to bind tb1 and tb2 as well, then he'll first click on tb1 and then tb2.

Comment: or maybe click on tb1 and drag it till tb2, indicating that tb1 is binded with tb2

Comment: please eloborate more by creating fiddler or plunkr

Comment: sorry for the delay in response. The link to fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/1p4fk13o/